# Syncing multiple mysql databases over a VPN

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework, synchronization

we're going to deploy a web application which is going to run on premise for a couple of locations scattered all over the world.

Now what we want to do is have all of them have their own database running their own information BUT sync all their information to 1 parent database so we can take a look at their activities from head office.

What would be the best way to do this? I think all records must have their own GUID so they can get updated accordingly.

Sincerely,

Bob.

Comment: The application we've built is an ERP.
We want to be able to see invoices from other subsidiaries.

All subsidiaries have their own category id so everyone is part of 1 big database separated by their cat_id

The parent database will have all cat_id's and head office can view all cat_id's.

Comment: And what data do you want to sync with the parent server ?

Comment: All the database entries, invoices , costumers , addresses, logs ..

Comment: Right, is the database 'schema' same for all (parent and subsidiaries) ?

Comment: Yes that is correct, Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Then what you are looking for is a master/slave replication configuration. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html

Comment: though it's not actually a slave, it should be master to master as every database is running it's own environment (incremental key etc).
In a master to master scenario you'd have a problem with key clashing.

Comment: There appears to be a fundamental error in the way you have structured the application. If the schema is exactly the same for all your setups you should have created an additional table that would map between the different applications. This way you would not need to sync databases and you could make use of replication when scaling. Having said that, considering your current setup, this is an issue that will need to be addressed on the application layer not database layer. Maybe you can write a script that will update your database with the relevant data and set it up as a cronjob.